# Move running process to background

Tags: linux, bash

How do you move a running process to the background? For example, type the command

```
sleep 60
```

on the command line and try moving that process to the background.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process and use `bg` to move it into the background. `fg` will move it back into the foreground.