# Single shortcut to move a running process to the background in bash

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I know how to move a process to the background by suspending it first, discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/q/409698/266986) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/255612/264276):

1. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
2. Run either `%&` or `bg`

However I'd like to do this without interrupting the process too much (not have it paused for ages while I type to start it up again). For example if it's playing audio and I don't want to interfere. It looks like there's no way to actually move it while running (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/186343/196639) and [this](https://superuser.com/q/595743/264276)), but I'll happily accept a single shortcut that does both the above operations in one step.

A similar question is here, but about zsh: [How can I do Ctrl-Z and bg in one keypress to make process continue in background?](https://superuser.com/questions/378018/how-can-i-do-ctrl-z-and-bg-in-one-keypress-to-make-process-continue-in-backgroun)

Comment: I assume that you already know that you can start a process like this? `mp3blaster song.mp3 &`? (The & starts it in the background).

Comment: @Hennes yep, I'm more interested in the case when I have something already running in the foreground, whether I've brought the wrong job to the foreground or just didn't expect to want to run something else in the meantime.

Comment: have you looked at [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr)? It allows you to 'grab' a process into the current screen. So you can start a new 'screen' session and then grab a long-running process from a different terminal and 'pull' it into the new screen session. And as this is a 'screen' session you can then disconnect and it carries on running. It's not backgrounding the process as such, but it might serve your purpose. And I think it is available via apt-get for debian derivatives.

Comment: @gogoud thanks, that sounds pretty decent ([more here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4035/54030)), though at the moment I'm looking for as light weight as possible and minimizing the time the process is suspended.

Comment: @jozxyqk That other question is about `zsh` and this is about `bash`

Comment: @KevinPanko fair point. I guess I assumed the same could be done pretty easily in bash.

Answer (score 0):

The commands can certainly be [combined](https://superuser.com/q/595743/264276), but triggering them is difficult.

One option is binding [Ctrl-Z in the shell](https://superuser.com/a/161922/264276) so you can hit it once to suspend and again to `bg`.

My solution is to [set a global shortcut to run a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2832/54030) which does the work.
Firstly, the [PID of the shell running in the active terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2041532/1888983) is obtained. Then [get the process in the foreground](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152140/54030), and finally [suspend and resume it](https://superuser.com/q/595743/264276). The same works if you want to kill it.

An annoying issue is KDE's konsole which has a single process for every terminal window. I found the answer here, or at least it pointed me in the right direction: http://wundermark.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/the-sick-and-twisted-world-of.html?m=1

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#get the active window
WID=$( xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | grep -o '0x[0-9a-f]\+' )

#get the parent's process ID (looks like I don't need this as there's only ever one konsole/gnome-terminal process running)
TPID=$( xprop -id $WID _NET_WM_PID | grep -o '[0-9a-f]\+' )

#get the window class, to check what terminal is running
TERM=$( xprop -id $WID WM_CLASS | grep -o 'konsole\|gnome-terminal' ) #change this to match your terminal. only tested with konsole

#quit if a terminal is not active
if [[ -z "$TERM" ]] ; then
    exit -1
fi

#get bash PID for the window, somehow
if [[ "$TERM" == "konsole" ]] ; then
    #this seems really really roundabout, but here goes..
    #for every konsole window (which may have many tabs/sessions)
    for WINDOW in $( qdbus org.kde.konsole /Windows org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect | grep "node name" | grep -o "[0-9]\+" ) ; do
        #get the "current" session, which I guess is the active tab. seems to work
        SESSION=$( qdbus org.kde.konsole /Windows/$WINDOW org.kde.konsole.Window.currentSession )

        #get the window ID from the environment variables (why is not available via qdbus??)
        KWID=$( qdbus org.kde.konsole /Sessions/$SESSION org.kde.konsole.Session.environment | grep WINDOWID | grep -o "[0-9]\+" )

        #convert it to hex, to match the query at the top
        KWID=$( printf "0x%x\n" $KWID )

        #if this active tab is in the active window, it's the one we want. grab the PID of the shell
        if [[ "$WID" == "$KWID" ]] ; then
            SHELL_PID=$( qdbus org.kde.konsole /Sessions/$SESSION org.kde.konsole.Session.processId )
            break
        fi
    done
else
    ps --ppid $TPID #<- need to figure out which bash PID for the WID, as above for KDE
    echo "only works for KDE atm. sorry"
    exit -1
fi

echo WID=$WID PID=$PID TERM=$TERM SHELL_PID=$SHELL_PID

#find the foreground process
ps -O stat --ppid $SHELL_PID | grep -v PID | while read CHILD ; do
    if [[ -n "$(echo $CHILD | awk '{print $2}' | grep \+)" ]] ; then
        PID=$( echo $CHILD | awk '{print $1}' )
        kill -SIGSTOP $PID
        sleep 0.0001 #??
        kill -SIGCONT $PID
        break
    fi
done
```

This works just fine. For example,

```
>>> sleep 100 #press shortcut here

[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 100
>>> jobs #check it's been restarted
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
>>>
```

However it does rely on the window manager being able to set global shortcuts and being able to get the active terminal and shell, which is pretty damn roundabout. I guess there might also be issues if say ssh is running, not sure.